# How do I get past the ledge outside the kitchen in Machinarium?

Tags: machinarium

I forgot where I was going and ended up on ledge outside kitchen a second time.

[image]

I don't have the oil can or other inventory items so no way to start the motor. Is there anyway off?  Or do I have to start the game over?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question, @Betty? It'll help us know exactly where you are. :) If you're running the Steam version, the default key is F12.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to start the game over.  Simply talk to the girl robot and get her to fill the motor with oil a second time.